# Iterating over named regex groups in Rust

Tags: rust

I wish to extract all named groups from a match into a HashMap and I'm running into a "does not live long enough" error while trying to compile this code:

```
extern crate regex;

use std::collections::HashMap;
use regex::Regex;

pub struct Route {
    regex: Regex,
}

pub struct Router<'a> {
    pub namespace_seperator: &'a str,
    routes: Vec<Route>,
}

impl<'a> Router<'a> {
    // ...

    pub fn path_to_params(&self, path: &'a str) -> Option<HashMap<&str, &str>> {
        for route in &self.routes {
            if route.regex.is_match(path) {
                let mut hash = HashMap::new();
                for cap in route.regex.captures_iter(path) {
                    for (name, value) in cap.iter_named() {
                        hash.insert(name, value.unwrap());
                    }
                }
                return Some(hash);
            }
        }
        None
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Here's the error output:

```
error: `cap` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:23:42
   |>
23 |>                     for (name, value) in cap.iter_named() {
   |>                                          ^^^
note: reference must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the block at 18:79...
  --> src/main.rs:18:80
   |>
18 |>     pub fn path_to_params(&self, path: &'a str) -> Option<HashMap<&str, &str>> {
   |>                                                                                ^
note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the for at 22:16
  --> src/main.rs:22:17
   |>
22 |>                 for cap in route.regex.captures_iter(path) {
   |>                 ^
```

Obviously I still have a thing or two to learn about Rust lifetimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's follow the lifetime lines:

- [`route.regex.captures_iter(path)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.captures_iter) creates a [`FindCapture<'r, 't>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/regex/struct.FindCaptures.html) where the lifetime `'r` is that of `route.regex` and the lifetime `'t` is that of `path`
- this iterator yields a `Captures<'t>`, only linked to the lifetime of `path`
- whose method [`iter_named(&'t self)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/regex/struct.Captures.html#method.iter_named) yields a [`SubCapture<'t>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/regex/struct.SubCapturesNamed.html) itself linked to the lifetime of `path` *and* the lifetime of the `cap`
- this iterator yields a `(&'t str, Option<&'t str>)` so that both keys and values of the `HashMap` are linked to the lifetime of `path` *and* the lifetime of the `cap`

Therefore, it is unfortunately impossible to have the `HashMap` outlive the `cap` variable as this variable is used by the code as a "marker" to keep the buffers containing the groups alive.

I am afraid that the only solution without significant re-structuring is to return a `HashMap<String, String>`, as unsatisfying as it is. It also occurs to me that a single capture group may match *multiple* times, not sure if you want to bother with this.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on lifetimes. Unfortunately I am still getting the same error with this new hint: 


note: reference must be valid for the lifetime 'b as defined on the block at 39:92...

pub fn path_to_params<'b>(&'b self, path: &'b str) -> Option<HashMap<&'b str, &'b str>> {

Comment: Do I need to set a lifetime for cap? If so, how do I go about doing that? It seems more complex in for loops.

Comment: @eltiare: Note that I did not put `'b` in as many places as you did. I left it off of `self` and the keys of the `HashMap`. Did it not work without it?

Comment: No, the compiler gave a suggestion to put the `'b` lifetime on `self`. I probably don't need it on the keys, though.

Comment: @eltiare: Actually, my answer is wrong. I need to go back and change it as a careful examination of the Regex API revealed that it somehow unified the lifetimes of names and values. (I wish I could test it on play Rust :x).

Comment: @eltiare: Answer edited, this may work much better (but once again, I cannot test it on play Rust :x).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122015/discussion-between-eltiare-and-matthieu-m).

Comment: You can use Regex on the alternative [playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=37c5cf2d83c33220431c871b5d199d6d)

Comment: @eltiare: "Fixed" using `String`: http://play.integer32.com/?gist=37b3697ca1aca172e7ff48fc20d377ca

Comment: @Matthew: In this particular case I don't think I have to worry about repeated matches. Thank you so much!

Comment: This [should be fixed](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/regex/pull/230/commits/47bd416e1d380d672f267d13b161961334f04505) with version 1.0 of regex. Note: *It was always possible to work around this by using indices.*

Comment: @Shepmaster: This might be worth an answer of its own, the patch itself won't be useful, but a code sample showing how to use the indices would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

[Matthieu M. already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39184570/155423) the lifetime situation well. The good news is that the regex crate recognized the problem and [there's a fix in the pipeline for 1.0](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/regex/pull/230/commits/47bd416e1d380d672f267d13b161961334f04505).

As stated in the commit message:

> It was always possible to work around this by using indices.

It is *also* possible to work around this by using [`Regex::capture_names`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.capture_names), although it's a bit more nested this way:

```
pub fn path_to_params(&self, path: &'a str) -> Option<HashMap<&str, &str>> {
    for route in &self.routes {
        if let Some(captures) = route.regex.captures(path) {
            let mut hash = HashMap::new();
            for name in route.regex.capture_names() {
                if let Some(name) = name {
                    if let Some(value) = captures.name(name) {
                        hash.insert(name, value);
                    }
                }
            }
            return Some(hash);
        }
    }
    None
}
```

Note that I also removed the outer `is_match` — it's inefficient to run the regex once and then again.

Comment: Is it still more efficient if you have a lot of regex's to match against?

Comment: @eltiare you should always verify bold statements from people on the Internet ;-) Benchmarking would be a good idea. That being said, I can't imagine that the capture method would be multiple times more complex; my gut says maybe 5% slower. That would indicate that 20 regexes would be the tipping point (if you always checked all 20). Benchmarking would be interesting!